# JSP + JSTL + jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I am new in webpage development with Java. For now, I am going to start a webapps project with JSP. But I have few questions:

1. I using JSP with MVC practice. Can I avoid to use any framework? Spring, Struts and ..
2. JSTL and EL are must in JSP?
3. jQuery provide nice UI but it is AJAX?

Until this stage, my plan for my project is using JSP + JSTL + jQuery. Hope someone can give some advice on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You of course can avoid using any MVC framework, but why would you? Do you like reinventing the wheel? Frameworks are there to help being more productive and writing better code.
2. Yes, they are a must.
3. JQuery doesn't provide any UI. It's a JavaScript library. JQuery-UI does provide UI widgets. JQuery does provide AJAX-related functions, which can be used by/with JQUery-UI widgets, of course. Asking if "it is AJAX" doesn't make much sense. Have you understood what AJAX is?

Using JSP + JSTL + JQuery is OK, and is quite common. But I wouldn't avoid using an MVC framework. They are useful.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer.  I will add in spring framework then..  for what I know , to use el and jstl we need to download the jar file and import to project right? Ya, my mistakes on jquery..